# working on many to many table and more attributes are required in third table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to save data in  third table in many to many relation but
data is not saving 
user model

```
public function Jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job','App\Models\Job_User','user_id','job_id');
}
```

job model

```
public function Users()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','App\Models\Job_User','job_id','user_id');
}
```

controller for saving data in third table is

```
public function JobApplied(Request $request){
        $applied= new Job_User();
        $applied->user_id = Auth::id();
        $applied->job_id = $request->job_id;
        $applied->cv = $request->cv;
        $applied->current_salary = $request->current_salary;
        $applied->expected_salary = $request->expected_salary;
        $applied->save();
        return redirect('searchjobs');
}
```

code of third table is

```
class Job_User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'user_id','job_id','cv','current_salary','expected_salary','status',
    ];
    protected $table = 'jobs_users';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the **many-to-many** relation incorrectly. You don't need a model for the intermediate table as Eloquent will handle it for you.

First of all, you need to define the relation in your models in a correct way. The second argument should be the name of the intermediate table, not the model. As you're using the default values for table name and foreign key column names, you can skip them and just do:

```
public function Jobs()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job');
}

public function Users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

If you want to have additional fields in the intermediate column, you need to define it when you define a relationship using **withPivot()** method:

```
public function Jobs()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job')->withPivot('cv','current_salary','expected_salary','status');
}

public function Users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withPivot('cv','current_salary','expected_salary','status');
}
```

Now, if you want to link a **Job** with a **User** and set the fields in the intermediate pivot table, you should use **save()** method on your relation:

```
$job->users()->save($user, ['cv' => $request->cv, 'current_salary' => $request->current_salary]);
```

or

```
$user->jobs()->save($job, ['cv' => $request->cv, 'current_salary' => $request->current_salary]);
```

Once you have data saved in your database you can retrieve data from intermediate pivot table using the **pivot** attribute of related model, e.g.:

```
foreach($user->jobs as $job) {
  echo $job->pivot->current_salary;
}
```

or

```
foreach($job->users as $user) {
  echo $user->pivot->current_salary;
}
```

Check the docs for more information about handling **many-to-many** relationship with Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thankx  for helping .

Comment: where should i write save method you have written

Comment: where should i written the withPivot method ?? this is the confusion

Comment: Add withPivot to your relation definitions in your Job and User classes

Comment: ErrorException in BelongsToMany.php line 592:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\bridging_the_gap\app\Http\Controllers\PrivatePages\StudentController.php on line 76 and defined